# FluentValidation with conditional validations and with different rules on the entity properties

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation, json-schema-validator

I have an entity:

```
public class BookDto {
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? ExternalBookId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string? Cost { get; set; }
    public string? ExternalClientId { get; set; }
}
// Validators
public class CreateBookValidator : AbstractValidator<BookDto> {
    public CreateBookValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEmpty();
    }
}

public class CreateBookValidator : AbstractValidator<BookDto> {
    public CreateBookValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
            .Empty().Unless(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ExternalBookId));
        
        RuleFor(x => x.ExternalBookId)
            .Empty().Unless(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Id));
    }
}
```

I need to be able to validate the `BookDto` depended on different logic.
Let's say: I have book comes from API and other from FILE, I would like to have a validation on both of them but with different validation logic.
Without being need to replicate hundreds of files of the "same" logic, can it be done?

Tried to create a json schema in DB but there's too much to take care of and not everything is working as expected.
For example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "externalBookId": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "cost": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "externalClientId": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [ // this part not working
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "id": { "type": "string" }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": ["id"],
        "not": { "required": ["externalBookId"] }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "externalBookId": { "type": "string" }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": ["externalBookId"],
        "not": { "required": ["id"] }
      }
    }
  ],
  "required": ["name", "externalClientId"]
}
```

Here is how I try to use it:

```
public T? Validate(string jsonData) {
        string jsonSchema = File.ReadAllText("../Application/Book/book-schema.json");
        JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(jsonSchema);
         JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
        
        if (!jObject.IsValid(schema, out IList<ValidationError> validationErrors)) {
            throw new JsonValidationException(validationErrors);
        }

        return jObject.ToObject<T>();
    }
```

I wanted to keep all of schemas in DB and load them on each type of entity to be able to validate different types of requests aka FILE/API.

Can anyone suggest how to solve my issue?

Comment: Did you have a look into [Rulesets](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/rulesets.html)?

Comment: so you mean that I can create a ruleset for each type of request for the validation? How you would suggest to keep in the solution? I hate a lot dirty solution with a lot of "if" statements and many possibilities for bugs.

Comment: Well, validation is aimed at types. Now if you need different sets of validation based on the instances' origins, then you can make validation extension methods for each namespace you are in. Or you can directly name a rule set. Or if you are in two different assemblies you could have two different validators. Those are the options I could name from the top of my head.

Comment: I see, but there's an issue with mediatr and validation, cause seems it's never hit validation error, do you familiar with CQRS Clean Arch solution?

Comment: Where do you expect it to be hit? Are you using a validation Middleware? Do you call them explicitly?

Comment: Middleware but still no luck never hits the validation logic

Comment: I found why the validation didn't worked. It's because I checked the dto and the command it self